# Find row index using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="formRow js-TextBox"><a></div>  <------ index 0
  <div class="formRow js-Image"><a></div> <------ index 1
  <div class="formRow js-TextBox"><a></div><------ index 2
  <div class="formRow js-ImageList"><------ index 3
  <div class="formRow js-Image"><a></div> <-- **This should return 3 but is returning 4 because I search index on the basis of formRow**
</div>
```

Code to find the `formRow` index

```
var parent = $(this).parents("div.formRow");
var rowIndex = parent.parent().find("div.formRow").index(parent);
```

Please refer to above code and advise how I can find the index of `formRow` for which I have clicked on anchor element `a`.

The problem is that the last form row contains another `formRow`, but I want the index of parent form row.

Comment: information is not complete??  `this` refers here to which element??

Comment: @diEcho - I think this is the clicked element - A tag

Comment: "this" is the anchor tag which was clicked

Comment: You'd just call `$(this).parent().index()`. But you can't get 3 for the last row unless you do a check further up to DOM tree to see whether there is another `formrow` parent

Comment: Maybe it would be better to bind the click event handler to the divs instead.... what are you doing in the event handler? What is the purpose of the links?

Comment: unfortunately i cannot change the selectors.

Comment: working perfectly here : see http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/38UrA/1/ ; actually your div is not structured  invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the above - I'd add another css class - primaryRow to the first three and use that instead of formRow in the jQuery expression

OK - The run this code:

```
 $('.parent > div').addClass('primaryRow');
```

to add the class.

Then

```
 var rowIndex = $('.primaryRow').index($(this).parents().find('.primaryRow'));
```

Comment: row "<div class="formRow js-Image"><a></div>" is created dynamically inside row with index 3 so the parent row can be child for another row

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove ambiguity and provide the row number to the element at render time, i.e.

```
<div class="formRow js-TextBox" id="row<%= rownumber %>"><a></div>
```

Or as the ID to the anchor:

```
<div class="formRow js-TextBox"><a id="row<%= rownumber %>"></div>
```

There are a multitude of ways to approach this. I always find that if something seems to hard then I'm approaching it from the wrong direction (or just plain wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$('a').click(function(){
var i = $(this).parents('.parent > .formRow').index('.parent > .formRow');
alert(i);
    return false;
});
```

Check it out: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/nGczj/)